Enhancing Line Connections and Text Alignment in TikZ Diagram
I'm working on creating an image using the TikZ package in LaTeX. The current output is close to what I want, but there are some areas for improvement:

Line Connection: I need all the lines from the input nodes to connect and end up to the box of weight update
update node back to the sum node.
Text Alignment: The text alignment needs improvement, especially for
the labels above and below the nodes.
Overall Alignment: Ensuring all elements are properly aligned with
each other can make the diagram more visually appealing and easier
to understand.

Could you provide suggestions on how to achieve these improvements in my TikZ code?
The code:
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, node distance=2cm, auto, align=center]
    % Input units
    \node (b) [circle, draw, minimum size=1cm,thick] {$b$};
    \node (x1) [circle, draw, minimum size=1cm, below of=b, node distance=1.5cm,thick] {$X_1$};
    \node (x2) [circle, draw, minimum size=1cm, below of=x1, node distance=1.5cm,thick] {$X_2$};
    \node (dots) [below of=x2, node distance=1cm,thick] {$\vdots$};
    \node (xn) [circle, draw, minimum size=1cm, below of=dots, node distance=1cm,thick] {$X_n$};

    % Aggregation function node
    \node (sum) [circle, draw, minimum size=5cm,thick, align=center, right=2.5cm of $(b)!0.5!(xn)$] {
        $\displaystyle z = b + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i$
    };
    
    % Threshold function
    \node (threshold) [right of=sum, node distance=2cm] {$\displaystyle f(z)$};

    % Output node
    \node (output) [right of=threshold, node distance=3.5cm] {$\boxed{\hat{y} \in \{-1, 1\}}$};

    % Error computation nodes
    \node (error) [below of=output, node distance=1.5cm] {$\boxed{\textit{error} = y - \hat{y}}$};
    \node (delta_w) [below of=error, node distance=1.5cm] {$\boxed{\Delta w = \eta (\textit{error}) x_k}$};
    \node (weight_update) [left of=delta_w, node distance=7.3cm] {$\boxed{w_{k+1} = w_k + \Delta w_k}$};

    % Arrows from inputs to sum
    \draw[->] (b) -- node [above] {$w_1$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (x1) -- node [above] {$w_2$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (x2) -- node [above] {$w_3$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (xn) -- node [above] {$w_n$} (sum);

    % Draw the line crossing all input arrows and extending beyond weight update
    %\draw[->] ($(b)!0.2!(xn) + (0,1.0)$) -- node [above] %{} (weight_update);

    % Arrow from sum to threshold
    %\draw[->] (sum) -- (threshold);

    % Arrow from threshold to output
    \draw[->, thick] (threshold) -- (output);

    % Arrow from output to error computation
    \draw[->, thick] (output) -- (error);

    % Arrow from error to delta_w
    \draw[->, thick] (error) -- (delta_w);

     % Arrow from delta_w to weight_update
    \draw[->, thick] (delta_w) -- (weight_update);

    % Arrow from weight_update to sum
    %\draw[->] (weight_update) |- (sum);

     % Aggregation function and threshold function labels
    \node [above of=sum, node distance=3.4cm] {Aggregation \\ function};
    \node [above of=threshold, node distance=3.5cm] {Threshold \\ function};
    \node [below of=weight_update, node distance=1cm] {Weight update};
    \node [below of=delta_w, node distance=1cm] {Error computation};


    % Dotted line for threshold function
    % Dotted line for threshold function
    \draw[dotted] (sum.north) -- (sum.south);


    % Input units label
    \node [below of=xn, node distance=1cm] {Input units};

   
    \end{tikzpicture}

Intened result:

Actual result:


Welcome. // A few hints for future questions: (1) Please limit your question to one problem only, se we'll continue to have 1 problem == 1 question, and each answer == 1 solution.  // (2) Please post only code which compiles (a few lines are just missing to achieve it).  /// Why do you think the problem is related to luatex?

I added luatex becuase is the compiled that i used to compile the code.

Ok, understand: so the compiler version should not be specific. // As a general remark, it's tempting to use positioning . However, when enough elements are added things start to get somewhat messy.  Alternatives: a) use absolute coordinates (which you name like you did) after having sketched the layout on a grid, e.g. on paper; b) using matrix , see the tutorial of the pgfmanual.

Ok, let's have a look. Assuming this is one of your early attempts with Tikz the results are fine, besides sooner or later you may want to do some code-cleanup. Personally I like your use of comments.
First to your questions, which are 2 too many:
Ad 1: Didn't get it. Perhaps a bent arrow back to the weights w1 .. wn is all you need visually?
Ad 2+3: See my comment. In drawings like this it's better to define a number of absolute coordinates first, name them and work from there. Like: \coordinate (circ) at (0,0); \node at (circ) {}; ... . Adjustments in such a design grid will be easier to my experience. matrix would impose a tabular grid, which might not be suited for all of your objects to be drawn.
Now my (intermediate) result from reworking your code a little, followed by some remarks.

General approach: leave your code as-is most of the time. Compiled with pdflatex, but that shouldn't matter (much).
newcommand\boxed[1]{#1} just passes the content, as I got compile errors. Later I understood that you want boxes, which I delegated to a self-defined style called box, see below. The point is: you have more control about appearance, e.g. like changing solid to dotted, colors, separations etc.
Some styles resulted from refactoring. circ reduces code, box, see above. I encourage you to go over your code (the options), identify, introduce and replace similar code patterns you use at least twice: cleaning-up, enhancing read-ability (understanding without thinking about it).
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
%       >=stealth, 
        >={Stealth},                % suggestion
        node distance=2cm, 
        auto, 
        align=center,
        % ~~~ refactoring (=simplifying) your code ~~~~~~~~~~
        circ/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm,},
        box/.style={draw},  % just as an example: ,inner sep=5pt},
    ]
...

Splitting the big circle into an empty node and one with math is something I would do here. Two purposes:

gain more control over positioning the formula
by naming it making alignment with text (Aggreg. func) easy

at ([xshift=-6mm]sum)  inside the node statement:

references the coordinate of (sum)
shifts it 6mm to the left

    % ~~~ suggestion: split it and use a relative shift ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (sum) [circle, draw, minimum size=5cm,thick, align=center, right=2.5cm of $(b)!0.5!(xn)$] {};
    \node (zz) at ([xshift=-6mm]sum) {$\displaystyle z = b + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i$};


A similar thing can be done wrt the upper labels:

name it e.g. lblA
shift it (in y-direction) wrt to (zz) and (threshold)
draw an arrow using a relative coordinate -- +(0,-1);

     % Aggregation function and threshold function labels
%    \node [above of=sum, node distance=3.4cm]          {Aggregation \\ function};
%    \node [above of=threshold, node distance=3.5cm]    {Threshold \\ function};

    % ~~~ let's center text above the 2 math-parts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (lblA) at ([yshift=35mm]zz)                   {Aggregation \\ function};
    \node (lblT) at ([yshift=35mm]threshold)            {Threshold \\ function};
    \node [below of=weight_update, node distance=1cm]   {Weight update};
    \node [below of=delta_w, node distance=1cm]         {Error computation};
    
    \draw [->] (lblA) -- +(0,-1);
    \draw [->] (lblT) -- +(0,-1.7);

The dotted separator can be moved easily using polar notation:
%    \draw[dotted] (sum.north) -- (sum.south);  % .south == .-90 == .270 in polar notation
    \draw[dotted] (sum.60) -- (sum.-60);

Suggestions in hindsight

identify and introduce more self-defined styles (clean-up, control-in-one-place-only)
perhaps name a few more coordinates
perhaps replace some the positioning notation by x- and yshifts as shown for more control

Code
\newcommand\boxed[1]{#1}% just pass it through to get things up and running
                        % replaced by box-style, which allows for more tuning

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}   % were also missing
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}        % suggestion

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
%       >=stealth, 
        >={Stealth},                % suggestion
        node distance=2cm, 
        auto, 
        align=center,
        % ~~~ refactoring (=simplifying) your code ~~~~~~~~~~
        circ/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=1cm,},
        box/.style={draw},  % just as an example: ,inner sep=5pt},
    ]
    % Input units
    \node (b)   [circ,thick] {$b$};
    \node (x1)  [circ,below of=b, node distance=1.5cm,thick] {$X_1$};
    \node (x2)  [circ,below of=x1, node distance=1.5cm,thick] {$X_2$};
    \node (dots)[below of=x2, node distance=1cm,thick] {$\vdots$};
    \node (xn)  [circ,below of=dots, node distance=1cm,thick] {$X_n$};

    % Aggregation function node
%    \node (sum) [circle, draw, minimum size=5cm,thick, align=center, right=2.5cm of $(b)!0.5!(xn)$] {
%        $\displaystyle z = b + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i$
%    };

    % ~~~ suggestion: split it and use a relative shift ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (sum) [circle, draw, minimum size=5cm,thick, align=center, right=2.5cm of $(b)!0.5!(xn)$] {};
    \node (zz) at ([xshift=-6mm]sum) {$\displaystyle z = b + \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i$};
    
    % Threshold function
    \node (threshold) [right of=sum, node distance=2cm] {$\displaystyle f(z)$};

    % Output node
    \node (output) [right of=threshold, node distance=3.5cm,box] {$\boxed{\hat{y} \in \{-1, 1\}}$};

    % Error computation nodes
    \node (error) [below of=output, node distance=1.5cm,box] {$\boxed{\textit{error} = y - \hat{y}}$};
    \node (delta_w) [below of=error, node distance=1.5cm,box] {$\boxed{\Delta w = \eta (\textit{error}) x_k}$};
    \node (weight_update) [left of=delta_w, node distance=7.3cm,box] {$\boxed{w_{k+1} = w_k + \Delta w_k}$};

    % Arrows from inputs to sum
    \draw[->] (b)  -- node [above] {$w_1$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (x1) -- node [above] {$w_2$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (x2) -- node [above] {$w_3$} (sum);
    \draw[->] (xn) -- node [above] {$w_n$} (sum);

    % Draw the line crossing all input arrows and extending beyond weight update
    %\draw[->] ($(b)!0.2!(xn) + (0,1.0)$) -- node [above] %{} (weight_update);

    % Arrow from sum to threshold
    %\draw[->] (sum) -- (threshold);

    % Arrow from threshold to output
    \draw[->, thick] (threshold) -- (output);

    % Arrow from output to error computation
    \draw[->, thick] (output) -- (error);

    % Arrow from error to delta_w
    \draw[->, thick] (error) -- (delta_w);

     % Arrow from delta_w to weight_update
    \draw[->, thick] (delta_w) -- (weight_update);

    % Arrow from weight_update to sum
    %\draw[->] (weight_update) |- (sum);

     % Aggregation function and threshold function labels
%    \node [above of=sum, node distance=3.4cm]          {Aggregation \\ function};
%    \node [above of=threshold, node distance=3.5cm]    {Threshold \\ function};

    % ~~~ let's center text above the 2 math-parts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (lblA) at ([yshift=35mm]zz)                   {Aggregation \\ function};
    \node (lblT) at ([yshift=35mm]threshold)            {Threshold \\ function};
    \node [below of=weight_update, node distance=1cm]   {Weight update};
    \node [below of=delta_w, node distance=1cm]         {Error computation};
    
    \draw [->] (lblA) -- +(0,-1);
    \draw [->] (lblT) -- +(0,-1.7);


    % Dotted line for threshold function
    % Dotted line for threshold function
%    \draw[dotted] (sum.north) -- (sum.south);  % .south == .-90 == .270 in polar notation
    \draw[dotted] (sum.60) -- (sum.-60);


    % Input units label
    \node [below of=xn, node distance=1cm] {Input units};

   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

P.S.: Here's a mockup of my alignment proposal. The lower 2 elements could be even a bit more to the left.


I would like to express my gratitude for your comprehensive response. It was particularly helpful for someone with limited knowledge of Tikz. I am currently utilising LuaLatex as I am uncertain whether I wish to utilise Greek texts with the Time New Roman font exclusively in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. In contrast to pdfLatex, which only supports the Babel font, LuaLatex offers a wider range of typographical options. Ideally, a line should be drawn through the weights, ending with the term w_{k+1}(this is not essential and it can be omitted).

Thank you. // Understand. Though it's possible to enter such a line and intersecting circles, it's a bit tedious to code. I doubt it would really make your visual message more evident. // I think from both placements and text (weight update) it's already quite obvious what's going on, a kind of feedback. // Perhaps it's enough to make alignment unique here: move "Input units" away to give space, let the w1.. column align with w_k+1 in the box and the W in  "Weight" also, so that you'l have a clear w-column .... Will be hard to overlook. Will look like "update drives process".

See my P.S. which illustrates the idea.
